# How to make one class that shared with multiple obj

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in unity and I made a save system that saves to a public class PlayerStats this is not a MonoBehaviour but a class that has all the data init. My question is if there is a way if I change on var in the playerstats it change all the playerstats only having only one playerstats.

Answer (score 0):

if this class is an exposed `Serializable` then not really as the Serializer will (de)serialize them all independent from another into their according serialized objects.

---

You might want to rather go for a [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html).

These are mainly data container assets (similar to prefabs) you can create and then reference in multiple places so each change within such a `ScriptablObject` is reflected everywhere where it is used.

E.g.

```
// This attribute is required so you can create instances of this ScriptableObject via
// RightClick in the Assets -> Create -> Example
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Example : ScriptableObject
{
    // your public fields here like e.g.
    public int someInt;
}
```

As an extra: `ScriptableObject` is a `c#` class -> They follow all the usual rules and can implement certain methods, interfaces, can be inherited etc.

Comment: The class is Serializable

Answer (score 0):

i think you can make your **PlayerStats** class and variable should be static then, but the downside is that your **PlayerStats** class now is accessible from anywhere.